# Can you please explain to me what this error involves and how to debug the software causing it?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, xdvipdfmx, docker

I have a document that was previously (a year+ ago) built successfully. As part of the work then, I threw all the code into a repo on Github with actions that built the document as part of releases.  All was well.

Fast forward to now, and something somewhere is different and broken.  Locally and on Githubs infrastructure, I have errors involving fonts, resulting in a PDF not being generated.

I've pulled down the github action repo and the document repo and attempted to debug this locally.  I've gotten as far as the following error:

```
bash-5.1# xdvipdfmx -vv cv.xdv
<FONTMAP:/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/opt/texlive/texdir/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2021.08.10:1555
cv.xdv -> cv.pdf
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</usr/share/fonts/TTF/Nimbus-Sans-D-OT-Ultra-Light_327577.ttf@39.85pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Nimbus-Sans-D-OT-Ultra-Light_327577.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/share/fonts/TTF/Nimbus-Sans-D-OT-Ultra-Light_327577.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/share/fonts/TTF/Nimbus-Sans-D-OT-Ultra-Light_327577.ttf(Identity-H)

xdvipdfmx:warning: Font "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Nimbus-Sans-D-OT-Ultra-Light_327577.ttf" permits "Preview & Print" embedding only **

(CID:NimbusSansDOT-UltrLigh)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Nimbus-Sans-D-OT-Ultra-Light_327577.ttf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> font_id=</usr/share/fonts/TTF/Nimbus-Sans-D-OT-Ultra-Light_327577.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0,1>.
></usr/share/fonts/Type1/n019003l.pfb@39.85pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/share/fonts/Type1/n019003l.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/share/fonts/Type1/n019003l.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/share/fonts/Type1/n019003l(Identity-H)
>
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (1)

No output PDF file written.
```

That's running in a docker container that should contain the full TexLive distribution.  I've modified the entrypoint to get me a shell for debugging purposes.

High level overview of the setup:

- Template originally from https://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv
- Building with XeTeX via Github action defined at https://github.com/chrisRidgers/latex-action forked from https://github.com/xu-cheng/latex-action which in turn is using a full TexLive docker container.  Changes include the addition of a custom font in the form of an alpine package that would normally be installed as part of the entrypoint.sh when building the container.
- Document source at https://github.com/chrisRidgers/cv Github action referenced ^^^ configured to build.

I've built a modified version of the action locally having installed a bash shell, and changed the entrypoint to allow me to run commands manually and debug.  The following flow replicates the output mentioned above:

```
docker build --no-cache -t latex-action . # From latex-action repo directory
docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/data latex-action # From document repo directory

cd /data/src
xelatex -nopdf cv.tex
xdvipdfmx -vv cv.xdv
```

What's wrong with the above setup?  How can I debug it further?  How has a dockerised build suddenly broken?  For all that I've mentioned, which documentation is most relevant: I've done a lot of Googling.

Comment: Basic question (I don't know the answer), but where is that Nimbus font installed? Was it a dependency not gitted and is gone locally? Could another (Nimbus) font be used instead? The answer will probably turn on how font files are found/cached/catalogs updated/permissions etc by the separate engines, I'm expecting. P.S. Was the font set up with relevant access (e.g., admin)? Local permissions only happen a lot.

Comment: its in the form of alpine pacakge distributed in https://github.com/chrisRidgers/latex-action/blob/master/Dockerfile

And installed as part of the entrypoint https://github.com/chrisRidgers/latex-action/blob/7c48478d6e20009cb6e5c6b42701d51f4ab54c8b/entrypoint.sh#L42

As for location

Comment: its in the form of alpine pacakge distributed in https://github.com/chrisRidgers/latex-action/blob/master/Dockerfile

And installed as part of the entrypoint https://github.com/chrisRidgers/latex-action/blob/7c48478d6e20009cb6e5c6b42701d51f4ab54c8b/entrypoint.sh#L42

As for location of the ttf file: `usr/share/fonts/TTF/Nimbus-Sans-D-OT-Ultra-Light_327577.ttf`

And it is picked up by font tools like fc-list

```
bash-5.1# fc-list | grep -i nimbus
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Nimbus-Sans-D-OT-Ultra-Light_327577.ttf: Nimbus Sans D OT,Nimbus Sans D OT Ultra Light:style=Ultra Light,Regular```

Comment: I would have added more info like the above as part of the original question, however it was blocked as spam by stack overflow.

Comment: And to kind of answer your question, no.  At least not to my knowledge because other nimbus fonts also installed via

`apk --no-cache add libwmf`

And similarly referenced in https://github.com/chrisRidgers/cv/blob/3c126bcde76f82ea0a9e283945f54b89a2f1c46e/src/friggeri-cv.cls#L54